# I cannot get wx.Panel to refresh correctly

Tags: python, wxpython

I have an app where this module is included. The module's job is to get and load RSS feed into the app, depending on the RSS feed provider that the user chose. The module does its job perfectly when I do not try to remove the entries from the previous query.

When I add .Clear() method to the sizer, containing all the programmatically added rows in the UI from a query, they are removed from memory but remain in the UI. I tried lots of different methods to make the UI update, but it doesn't. So now each set of new query rows gets painted over the old query rows.

Here's the gist to the module. You can directly run it:
https://gist.github.com/TiMladenov/64e55cafd4200373ba1f9ab82160cc00

Steps to reproduce:
1. Select the first or second dropdown option
2. Then select the third one

This way the problem will be more obvious.

I have tried calling .Layout(), .Update(), .Fit() to their respective objects that are making this module work, but none seem to do their job. Or I failed somewhere....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were only missing one option for the `Clear()` method in the `wx.BoxSizer` class.

Change the line (87):

```
self.RssPanelList.Clear()
```

to:

```
self.RssPanelList.Clear(delete_windows=True)
```

The problem is that the method `Clear()` does not destroy the widgets by default. Therefore, you were emptying the sizer but the widgets remain and were painting on top of each other.

In the future it would be better if you post a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your chances of getting an answer will be a lot better with a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question.

Comment: So this method was the culprit all along. Always something new to learn in wxPython.

The issue is resolved. I appreciate a lot your assistance! Note taken, in future, I will use a MWE.

I was so annoyed yesterday. In another module, I'm doing almost the same things, but I remove any sizer elements manually with a for loop and the .Remove(item) method and no such problems were met.

Comment: For `Clear(delete_windows=True)` plus 1. We live and learn, I've always done it with a loop.